# Razor: add class to LabelFor if field is not valid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

In my form I have:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "", placeholder = "Full Name" })
```

**Q:** How to check if field is valid and add a class to the LabelFor if it's specific field is not valid?

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, if !valid: new { @class="error"} )
```

Answer (score 1):

You're along the right lines but try this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class= !ViewData.ModelState.IsValid ? "error" : ""} )
```

Using a ternary statement should work in this scenario as I use them myself on a frequent basis in normal DIV and INPUT HTML.

**Edit:** After chatting with Alex for a while in the StackOverflow chat system, this is the final working solution I came up with. Unfortunately, Alex is using Unobstrusive JQuery so the below code will only work if client side validation is not added.

```
@{
    var errorCollection = new ModelErrorCollection();

    if (ViewData.ModelState.Any(a => a.Value.Errors.Count > 0)) {
        errorCollection = ViewData.ModelState["PropertyName"].Errors;
    }
}

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.PropertyName, null, new { @class = 
        errorCollection.Any() ? "cssClassName" : "" })
```

Comment: where does `valid` come from?

Comment: Valid will be what ever you use for your if statement. A turnery statement is like saying there is only one of two options.

Comment: that is the problem i don't know how to check that field if it is valid or not

Comment: Let's try looking at it from this sceanrio, if it was a normal scenario how would you do the if statement? Are you passing some kind of Viewbag back from the action or some other variable to see if something is valid?

Comment: I'm not passing any variable from action method, the validation is done in a ViewModel with atributes

Comment: and in the view I use that model

Comment: So if I've got this right you are trying to change the colour of the text based on if the modelstate has forwarded an error? This wasn't specified, that can be done with CSS I think I'll update my answer in a moment

Comment: I've updated my answer, check the ternary statement now. If necessary I believe you can add `ViewData.ModelState.IsValid.Name` possibly, not 100% sure on this though

Comment: it deosn't seem to work, does it matter if I am using jquery unobtrusive validation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61216/discussion-between-damian-and-alex).